# Drag&drop from QListWidget to QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, qt, events, pyqt

I'm trying to implement drag&drop functionality from `QListWidget` to `QPlainTextEdit`.

I'm using `eventFilter` but for some reason the `QPlainTextEdit` gets only `Drag` event. `Drop` event never happens.

Source code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.listA = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.textedit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textedit.installEventFilter(self)
        self.listA.setDragEnabled(True)

        for widget in (self.listA, self.textedit):
            widget.setAcceptDrops(True)
            layout.addWidget(widget)

        for item in 'One Two Three Four Five Six'.split():
            self.listA.addItem(item)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.DragEnter and source is self.textedit):
            event.accept()
            return False
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Drop and source is self.textedit):
            print 'Drop'
            return False
        return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I handle `Drop` event and correct text to the `QPlainTextEdit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this example](http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?key=QApplicationInstallEventFiler&index=379) one needs to return `True` if an event has been filtered successfully. I'm actually not sure, but at least the drop appears to work

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.listA = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.textedit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.textedit.installEventFilter(self)
        self.listA.setDragEnabled(True)

        for widget in (self.listA, self.textedit):
            widget.setAcceptDrops(True)
            layout.addWidget(widget)

        for item in 'One Two Three Four Five Six'.split():
            self.listA.addItem(item)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.DragEnter and source is self.textedit):
            event.accept()
            print 'DragEnter'
            return True
        elif (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Drop and source is self.textedit):
            print 'Drop'
            return True
        else:
            return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
```